# Is there a suitable alternative to mlocate for macOS?

Tags: unix, spotlight, search

I would like to replicate the functionality of mlocate (not findutils) from Linux in macOS. I've tried the following alternatives, but each has its own downside:

- findutils: only world-readable files are indexed
- mdfind (spotlight): dot-files are not indexed

If I have a file with a leading dot that is not world-readable, neither of the above solutions will work.

The advantage of mlocate over both of these is that it will index all files, but will only allow the user to discover files they have permissions to read. So, I would be able to locate a hidden file that is not world readable, but is owned by me.

Are there any other suitable alternatives or workarounds for macOS?

Comment: Are you talking about [this mlocate](https://github.com/mlocate/mlocate)? May require some adaptions to compile on current macOS versions but should be useable as a starting point. And then run the `findutils` version of `updatedb` with `--localuser=root` to add all files.